# Notepad++ Regex Find Semicolon Second Last From Newline

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am trying to figure out how to do a find and replace on Notepad++ using regex, what I have is a bunch of lines with the following format

```
1 ; 2 ; 3 ; 4 ; AA ; AA BB
5 ; 6 ; 7 ; 8 ; AA ; BB CC
2 ; 4 ; 6 ; 0 ; AA ; DD EE
```

What I'd like to do is add a semicolon in between every instance of the last section like this:

```
1 ; 2 ; 3 ; 4 ; AA ; AA ; BB
5 ; 6 ; 7 ; 8 ; AA ; BB ; CC
2 ; 4 ; 6 ; 0 ; AA ; DD ; EE
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex in find:

```
 (\S+)$
```

(read as 'space', then the characters `(\S+)$`)

And this replace:

```
 ; $1
```

(read as 'space', semicolon, 'space' and 'dollar 1')

Make sure that you checked "Regular expression" and that ". matches newline" is unchecked!

`\S` matches non-spaces (non-newlines, non-carriage returns non-formfeeds) and the brackets stores the match in a variable `$1` in this case.

`$` matches the end of the line.

In the replace, we're putting space, semicolon, space then the stuff we earlier stored in `$1`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Find what: ([A-Z]+)\s+([A-Z]+)$
Replace with: $1 ; $2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Search for: (\w+)\s+(\w+)$
Replace with: \1 ; \2
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is the regex to match last two characters with a space:

```
(\s\w\w)$
```

Remember to add multiline flag to your regex.

Replace matched elements with `; $1`. $1 stays for first capturing group.

Demo: [regexr.com](http://regexr.com?36b8f)